# desplazamiento circular de elementos animados con react native

Tags: react-native, css-transform, animated

La tecnología utilizada es React Native y su librería Animated.
Comparto el siguiente componente que he creado para desplazar una figura  por la pantalla:

```
    const Animacion6 = () => {

    const [ animacion1 ] = useState(new Animated.Value(0))
    const [ animacion2 ] = useState(new Animated.Value(-50))

    useEffect(() => {
        Animated.loop(
        Animated.sequence([
            Animated.timing(animacion2, {
                toValue: -30,
                duration: 0,
                useNativeDriver: false
            }),
            Animated.timing(animacion1, {
                toValue: 60,
                duration: 500,
                useNativeDriver: false
            }),
            Animated.timing(animacion2, {
                toValue: 30,
                duration: 500,
                useNativeDriver: false
            }),
            Animated.timing(animacion1, {
                toValue: 0,
                duration: 500,
                useNativeDriver: false
            }),
            Animated.timing(animacion2, {
                toValue: -30,
                duration: 500,
                useNativeDriver: false
            }),
        ])
        ).start();
    }, [])

    const estiloAnimacion = {
        transform: [
            { translateY : animacion1},
            { translateX : animacion2},
        ]
    }

    return (
        <View style={{alignItems: 'center'}}>
            <Animated.View style={[styles.caja, estiloAnimacion]}>

            </Animated.View>
        </View>
    );
}

    const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    caja: {
        width: 10,
        height: 10, 
        backgroundColor: 'cornflowerblue'
    },
    })
    
    export default Animacion6;
```

Todo entendido hasta aquí. El problema que tengo es que quiero que este elemento realice una trayectoria circular y con los valores que le puedo dar a translateX y TranslateY, solo puedo moverlo en línea recta.
¿Alguien tiene alguna idea de cómo hacer para realizar una trayectoria circular?
Me gustaría hacerlo con Animated puro pero si esto no fuera posible, tampoco me importaría tener que utilizar otros recursos como imágenes gif o SVG, el problema es que no me hago a la idea de cómo se hace.
Toda ayuda se agradece aunque solo sean pistas. Muchas gracias!!